# iptables to disallow sending of "port closed"

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I would like iptables to disallow the sending of a "port closed" (RST ACK) in the OUTPUT chain.

I am not sure if this is correct:

```
--append OUTPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags RST,ACK RST,ACK --jump REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks correct. It would be more normal just to block the SYN packets from reaching the service in the first place though, rather than blocking the response like that.

Comment: Reason: If the daemon is listening, then I'm good. But if the daemon is unavailable, I do not want outgoing "port closed" packets.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what effect your rule (if any) actually would have; do a DROP instead of REJECT.
See [REJECT vs DROP when using iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/157375/iptables-reject-vs-drop).