# Telnet shows blank screen on port 443 but TCP handshake not done

Tags: networking, telnet

From my windows 10 machine (172.18.164.50) if I do a `telnet 172.20.187.10 443`
It shows a blank screen as if it is connected.

It is totally unespected because in theory a firewall is blocking the traffic to port `443`.

Looking in Message Analyser (filtering network card with source or destination  `172.20.187.10`) I see SYN message and Retransmit SYN, with no ACK-SYN reponse.

If I try a `telnet 172.20.187.10 666` it shows typical message "Could not open connection to..." In this case it is expected because there is nothing on the server listening on port `666`.

Again looking in Message Analyser I see the very same SYN messages (with different port number) with no ACK-SYN.

Why is telnet acting so differently if TCP messages look the same?

Comment: To test please use openssl - openssl s_client -connect 172.18.164.50:443 This will initiate the TLS handshake and tell you if the port is actually accessible & listening (as well as if it's configured properly for HTTPS if it is).

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/157375/reject-vs-drop-when-using-iptables

Comment: Thanks for the link. From the TCP client side how can I see if a REJECT is receveid? Is the server sending a new message? Which kind of message is, TCP, UDP?