# Do AWS Security Groups and rules and Network ACLs REJECT or DROP traffic?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, iptables, amazon-vpc

[AWS Security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html) and [AWS VPC Network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) are 2 solutions for controlling traffic in VPCs.

When rules in either deny an IP packet, do they [REJECT or DROP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Epeterb/network/drop-vs-reject) (in [the iptables sense](https://serverfault.com/questions/157375/reject-vs-drop-when-using-iptables))?

That is: are packets silently dropped, or does the firewall respond with a RST/ACK (tcp) or ICMP Port Unreachable packet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran some experiments here:
https://github.com/turtlemonvh/aws-network-experiments

Traffic denied by either AWS security group rules and network ACLs behaves identically to traffic encountering an iptables `DROP` rule (vs `REJECT` or `REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`). No response is sent in either case.