# Iptables --reject-with tcp-reset for non-TCP traffic

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, tcp

[Here](https://wiki.dieg.info/reject-with) I faced with a bit strange rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.26.95.20 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

This rule matches all the protocols from specific network and [rejects](https://serverfault.com/questions/157375/reject-vs-drop-when-using-iptables) it with TCP RST packet.
How is this supposed to work with non-TCP packets? If other end (10.26.95.20) sends UDP packet it then receives TCP RST? This looks extremely strange..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it makes no sense. IPTABLES also errors when I attempt to issue this on the command line (tested on CentoOS 8). It can only work if `-p tcp` is given which specifies that the rule is dealing with TCP traffic. Then it will work.